Unions & Intersection of Probability
I've had all three answers below marked wrong, and I am not sure how to proceed. I have included my thinking.

Suppose we are interested in the buying habits of shoppers at a particular grocery store with regards to whether they purchase apples, milk, and/or bread. Now suppose $30\%$ of all shoppers at this particular grocery store buy apples, $45\%$ buy milk, and $40\%$ buy a loaf of bread.
Let $A$ be the event that a randomly selected shopper buys apples, $B$ be the event that the same randomly selected shopper buys milk, and $C$ the event that the shopper buys bread. Suppose we also know (from data collected) the following information:

The probability that the shopper buys apples and milk is $0.20$.
The probability that the shopper buys milk and bread is $0.25$.
The probability that the shopper buys apples and bread is $0.12$.
The probability that the shopper buys all three items is $0.07$.

a) Find the probability that the shopper purchases at least one of the three items.

My attempt :
$P(A \cup B \cup C) = 
P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A \cap B)-P(B \cap C)-P(A \cap C)+P(A \cap B \cap C)=.30+.45+.40-.2-.25-.12 + .17 =0.75$

b) Find the probability that the shopper purchases none of the three items.

My attempt :
$P(A' \cup B' \cup C')=(1-.3) \times (1-.45) \times (1-.4)=.7 \times .45 \times .4 = .231$

c) Find the probability that the shopper buys milk and bread but not apples.

My attempt :
$P(A' \cap B \cap C)=(1-.3) \times .45 \times .4 =0.126$
EDIT
I have also tried doing this with naive probability and the answers are still not accepted.
a)
s=c(111, 110, 101, 011, 100, 001, 010, 000)
s_count=8
at_least_1= c(111, 110, 101, 011, 100, 001, 010)
at_least_1_ct=7
7/8=0.875
b)
none=c(111, 110, 101, 011, 100, 001, 010, 000)
1/8=0.125
c)
milk_and_bread=c(111, 110, 101, 011, 100, 001, 010, 000)
2/8=0.25

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Draw a Venn diagram. Imagine there are 100 shoppers and use the information given to fill in the number in each of the 8 regions. Then you might understand how to use the formulas you have memorized.

@EthanBolker I have drawn the venn diagram. It is of no help. Is there a way to do these problems with a data table?

There are certain issues which are not right in my answer ! I am temporarily deleting my answer , to recheck & update , later in the Day !

A and B should add up to 1.

I think your basic error is that you have assumed independence, which is not what this problem needs (nor does it give you reason to think there is independence). There should be no multiplications anywhere; the basic approach should be as in user2661923's answer, though I don't particularly see why a Venn diagram is inferior. It's how I did it and it took a minute or so.



c) Find the probability that the shopper buys milk and bread but not apples.

My attempt:   $P(A' \cap B \cap C)=(1-.3) \times .45 \times .4=0.126$

$$P(A' \cap B \cap C)=\mathbf{0.18}\ne0.126= P(A')\times P(B)\times P(C).$$ (The correct answer $\mathbf{0.18}$ is explained below.) Thus, events $A',B,C$ are not in fact mutually independent. So, events $A,B,C$ are also not independent.
Incidentally, note that

$P(X \cap Y \cap Z)=P(X)\times P(Y)\times P(Z){\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies}$ $X,Y,Z$ are independent
$X,Y,Z$ are pairwise independent ${\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies} P(X \cap Y \cap Z)=P(X)\times P(Y)\times P(Z).$



b) Find the probability that the shopper purchases none of the three items.

My attempt:   $P(A' \cup B' \cup C')=(1-.3) \times (1-.45) \times (1-.4)=.231$

You meant to write $P(A' \cap B' \cap C');$ unfortunately, as above, $$P(A' \cap B' \cap C')\ne P(A')\times P(B')\times P(C').$$


a) Find the probability that the shopper purchases at least one of the three items.

My attempt:   $P(A \cup B \cup C) =  P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A \cap B)-P(B
\cap C)-P(A \cap C)+P(A \cap B \cap C)=.30+.45+.40-.2-.25-.12 + .17 =0.75$

You misread $0.07$ as $0.17,$ so your answer is too big by $0.10.$

A CORRECT SOLUTION


Let $A$ be the event that a randomly selected shopper buys apples, $B$ be the event that the same randomly selected shopper buys milk, and $C$ the event that the shopper buys bread.


Why does the problem statement make $B$ stand for Milk instead of Bread? To lower the cognitive load, thereby working faster and less carelessly, it would be better to begin by redefining the sets as $A,M,B.$ However, below, I'm just sticking to the assigned set names, $A,B,C.$



$30\%$ of all shoppers buy apples
$45\%$ buy milk
$40\%$ buy a loaf of bread
probability that buys apples and milk is $0.20$
probability that buys milk and bread is $0.25$
probability that buys apples and bread is $0.12$
probability that buys all three items is $0.07$



A Venn diagram (with the probabilities scaled by $100)$ can capture the above information. Start from the last bullet point and work upwards.



c) Find the probability that the shopper buys milk and bread but not apples.


c) $\mathbf{0.18}$


b) Find the probability that the shopper purchases none of the three items.


b) $\mathbf{0.35}$


a) Find the probability that the shopper purchases at least one of the three items.


a) $1-0.35=\mathbf{0.65}$ (alternatively, add up the numbers in the circles then divide by $100).$

Thank you for the thoughtful response!

Thanks to Henry for commenting that you actually have $~8~$ linear equations in $~8~$ unknowns, rather than only $~7~$ equations, as I originally wrote.  I edited my answer accordingly.

Personally, when there are $~3~$ or more (basic) true/false conditions, giving rise to $~2^3 = 8~$ or more compound conditions, I prefer a truth table over a venn diagram.
I also regard the  original poster's approach to be overly complicated and prone to errors.
\begin{array}{| r | r | r | r |}
  \hline                       
  \text{variable} & \text{apples} & \text{milk} & \text{bread} \\
  \hline                       
  x_1 & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\
  \hline
  x_2 & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{F} \\
  \hline
  x_3 & \text{T} & \text{F} & \text{T} \\
  \hline
  x_4 & \text{T} & \text{F} & \text{F} \\
  \hline
  x_5 & \text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\
  \hline
  x_5 & \text{F} & \text{T} & \text{F} \\
  \hline
  x_7 & \text{F} & \text{F} & \text{T} \\
  \hline
  x_8 & \text{F} & \text{F} & \text{F} \\
  \hline
\end{array}
       x-1  x-2  x-3  x-4  x-5  x-6  x-7  x-8
E1 :    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0   = 0.30
E2 :    1    1    0    0    1    1    0    0   = 0.45
E3 :    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0   = 0.40
E4 :    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0   = 0.20
E5 :    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0   = 0.25
E6 :    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0   = 0.12
E7 :    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   = 0.07
E8 :    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1   = 1.0

The above tableau uses the problem's premises to create 8 linear equations in the 8 unknowns, $~x_1, \cdots, x_8,~$ based on the table.  Note that equation E8 is implied by the fact that exactly one of the mutually exclusive events represented by $~x_1, \cdots, x_8~$ must occur.
At this point, you don't know for sure that the problem is solvable, because you don't know whether the $~8~$ equations are independent of each other.  However, it is reasonable to presume, based on the perceived intent of the problem composer, that the problem is solvable.
Edit
If you are familiar with matrix theory, and you construct the $~8 \times 8~$ matrix represented by the above tableau, and you then find that the determinant of the matrix is non-zero, you would then have a guarantee that the problem is solvable.  However, I regard that analysis as overkill, for this problem.
You are being asked (in effect) to compute
$$1 - x_8 = x_1 + \cdots + x_7.$$
So, let's start with what can be derived:

Using E2 and E4, 
$x_5 + x_6 = 0.25.$

Using E1 and E4, 
$x_3 + x_4 = 0.10~$ and 
$x_1 + x_2 = 0.20.$


So, the entire problem has been reduced to computing $~x_7.~$
However, from the table, I see no way of directly computing $~x_7.~$
So, I will try a different approach.

Using E7 and E4, 
$x_1 = 0.7, ~x_2 = 0.13.$

Then, since $~x_1~$ is known, 
using E6 and E5, 
$~x_3 = 0.05, ~x_5 = 0.18.$


Now, the problem can be directly conquered.
Since $~x_1, ~x_3, ~$ and $~x_5~$ are known, E3 may be used to compute
$$x_7 = 0.10.$$
Therefore, from the previous results, you have that
$$(x_1 + x_2) = 0.20, ~(x_3 + x_4) = 0.10, ~(x_5 + x_6) = 0.25, ~x_7 = 0.10.$$
Therefore,
$$x_1 + \cdots + x_7 = 0.65 \implies x_8 = 0.35.$$
Also, the probability of buying both milk and bread, but not apples, is represented by
$$x_5 = 0.18.$$

You have 8 equations in 8 unknowns, since combined the probabilities add up to $1$.  You could say the probability of only bread $x_7=0.4 - 0.07 - (0.25-0.07)-(0.12-0.07)$.  Or you could use inclusion-exclusion to answer A with  $0.30+0.45+0.40-0.20-0.25-0.12+0.07$ and B with $1-0.30-0.45-0.40+0.20+0.25+0.12-0.07$

@Henry Good catch, about the (implicit) 8th equation.  I edited my answer accordingly.  With respect to the remainder of the analysis in your comment, I feel that it is important to compose my answer with the target audience of the original poster in mind.  As such, I believe it is best to forgo any elegance, and instead imagine what I might be thinking, as the original poster, at the point where I had just created the tableau of equations, and wasn't sure what my next step was.  ...see next comment

@Henry In such a position, not sure of my next step, I would simply try to investigate what deductions are possible, not being sure where they will lead.  So, I don't think that it is a good idea to provide an immediate formula for either $~x_7,~$ or the answer to question A.  Instead, I think it best for the original poster to witness a slow, cumbersome, derivation of one conclusion at a time.  I think that this type of approach will serve the original poster well if they encounter similar problems in the near future.  Later, as their intuition grows, they can develop elegance on their own.

I would have thought my $x_7$ expression was an intuitive approach: solely bread equals total  bread minus all three and minus just milk&bread and minus just apples&bread

@Henry As I was composing the answer, it was not immediately clear to me that $~x_7~$ would be the problem variable.  It became clear to me, only after I noticed that each of the three expressions $(x_1 + x_2), ~(x_3 + x_4), ~$ and $~(x_5 + x_6)~$ were known.  Further, once the equations are composed and I am focusing on the variables $~x_1, \cdots, x_8,~$ I stop considering what they represent, and instead focus only on finding their numeric values, via the equations.  I regard this type of tunnel vision as not necessarily bad, either for myself or the original poster.

@user2661923 Thank you for the thoughtful response!

I think that you are assuming independence (isn't that why you're multiplying probabilities), and also you might be misunderstanding what the problem is telling you.
I think the set-up is as follows, depicted as a Venn diagram, despite user2661923's relative distaste for those. :-)

The various facts of the question tell you

apples: $b+e+f+h = 30$
milk: $c+e+g+h = 45$
bread: $d+f+g+h = 40$
apples and milk: $e+h = 20$
apples and bread: $f+h = 12$
milk and bread: $g+h = 25$
apples, milk, and bread: $h = 7$
law of probability: $a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h = 100$

You'll need to figure out what each of the eight variables are to answer the questions. It's easiest to work out from the center.
